# XPath fails on an XML document in R

Tags: r, xpath, xml-parsing

I'll be glad to find some help with XML manipulation with R.

I'm trying to proceed XPath on my XML/TEI file. Here's its structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<text>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                <seg>
                        <name ref="Actr1235">Jen B.</name>frate M. <name ref="Actr1234">Léard B.</name> rhoncus orci quis luctus ultrices <note place="margin-left">1713 &amp; 1714</note>, a été
                        vehicula cursus nunc, at sagittis lorem aliquet sed <name ref="Actr1236"> Jaes L.</name>
                        aeman graeca <name type="place">Digo</name> iaculis volutpat risu <name ref="Cole14">la
                        Charias</name>. M. <name ref="Actr1236">Laure</name> bibendum augue erat, fermentum semper. M. <name ref="Actr1235">B.</name> bibendum augue erat, fermentum semper
                </seg>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

I'd like to extract all the attribute's values beginning with "Actr" inside `<name>` tags.
I've tried this XPath in an XMLeditor  `//tei:name/@ref[starts-with(., 'Actr')]` and it's working.

Now, I'm trying to do it with R to put the query's results in a dataframe, using XML package to parse the document

```
library(XML)
data1715<-xmlParse("My_document.xml")
name_query<-xpathSApply(data1715, "data(//tei:name/@ref[starts-with(., 'Actr')])", xmlValue)
```

It returns following error:

> XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix xmlXPathCompOpEval: parameter
>   error XPath error : Invalid expression Erreur dans
>   xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, path, fun, ..., namespaces =
>   namespaces,  :    error evaluating xpath expression
>   data(//tei:name/@ref[starts-with(., 'Actr')])

How do you define namespace in this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but it looks like it doesn't recognize the namespace associated with the `tei:` prefix. If there's a way to declare a namespace in R, try that; otherwise use the wildcard for that element `//*:name/@ref[...]`.

Comment: Please read up on the differences between XPath and XQuery (which is a superset of XPath), and use the right tags. `xpathSApply` does not support XQuery (which is not a problem, you're only using a simple XPath expression in your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XML` package doesn't handle default namespaces very well. You need to be explicit about assigning a name to the namespace before you can use xpath style expressions. How about something like

```
xpathSApply(data1715, 
     "//tei:name/@ref[starts-with(.,'Actr')]", 
     unname,
     namespaces=c(tei=getDefaultNamespace(data1715)[[1]]$uri))
```

Note I also removed `data()` and changed `xmlValue`. I'm not sure what you were trying to do with `data()`, but here we are returning attributes and `xmlValue` doesn't appear to like working with attributes.

Comment: Perfect. There's one bracket missing at the end though. It returns the list of all the attribute's values beginning with "Actr". Thanks a lot.